# HTTP Socket Reader in C#

Tags: c#, sockets, http

Let's say I want to implement custom HTTP content forwarding logic from local port X to port Y. To do that I need to open TcpListener on port X and forward all HTTP requests to port Y.

The problem is I need to parse HTTP data to do that. Is there any implementation of simple HttpReader with interface like this?

```
var reader = new HttpReader(socket);
byte[] data = reader.ReadRequest();
byte[] data2 = DoSomething(data);
reader.WriteResponse(data2);
```

Comment: What do you mean parse HTTP data? If you mean the headers, you could easily write your own small parser that converts them into keyvalue pairs.

Comment: I mean everything, including body. It is not so simple as you think.